# Need to get output as lists rather than strings in Popen or any other system commands

Tags: python, list, popen, subprocess

I am trying to run a command from Python script(using Popen()) get the output as list, instead of string.

For Example, When I use Popen(), it gives the output as string. For commands like "vgs, vgdisplay, pvs, pvdisplay", I need to get the output as lists and should be able to parse it row and column, so that I can do the necessary action(like deleting the already existing Vg's etc etc). I was just wondering, if it is possible to get as lists or atleast convert into lists....

I started learning python a week ago, so I might have missed some simple tricks, please pardon me.....

Comment: `'the string'.split()`

Comment: @JBernardo put that as an answer.

Comment: okay so what if I want to convert it into, rows and columns.... for exmaple "vgs --noheadings -0 vg_name,vg_size" will give me list of vgs name and sizes in two columns. In that case, is there a way to convert it directly into lists with 2 columns and N number of rows.? PS:I can think of a logic using the split() itself, but just curious, if there any other idea available... Thanks

Comment: @howtechstuffworks : You'll have to write the logic yourself.  It shouldn't be too hard.  With the infinite number of ways that the string could be formatted, it is impossible for python to know how to split the string up for you.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense..... Just wanted to know, if I am missing out or something... Thanks Everyone...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to elaborate on the existing comments

```
from subprocess import PIPE
import subprocess
pro = subprocess.Popen("ifconfig", stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
data = pro.communicate()[0].split()
for line in data:
    print "THIS IS A LINE"
    print line
    print "**************"
```